# How to copy a file in capistrano script without throwing error if source file does not exist?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I am using capistrano to deploy my php application.I have a requirement to copy a list of  configuration files from previous release to new release. The list is maintained in an array. When I am looping over this array to copy from previous to current release , in case the source file is not found it throw an error and further execution stops. I want the script to ignore such case and keep executing next command printing a simple message if source file does not exist. I tried using command like following, but no luck:
 `run "test -f /tmp/myfile && cp -p /tmp/myfile /home/admin`

or even

```
if(File.exists?("/tmp/myfile"))

 run "cp -p /tmp/myfile /home/admin" 


else

  print " file doesnot exist"

end
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
run <<-CMD
  if [ -f /tmp/myfile ]; then \
    cp -p /tmp/myfile /home/admin; \
  else \
    echo 'myfile does not exist'; \
  fi
CMD
```

Remember that all capistrano `run` commands are executed on the remote server, and 
only an exit value of `0` indicates success.
The result of `"test -f /tmp/myfile && cp -p /tmp/myfile /home/admin` would 
still be `1` if `/tmp/myfile` does not exist. You could use `||` to 
call `echo` with a message that the file does not exist:

```
test -f /tmp/myfile && cp -p /tmp/myfile /home/admin && echo myfile does not exist
```

Which is the same thing.